# How to limit numbers after comma using Decimal?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a number from database (Clickhouse), and this number is limited with only two digits after comma on the database level. So I always have something like `34.23`, `2323.23`, `324234.3`, and so one (in our region we use dot to split fractional part of number).

And I have to multiply that number hardcoded numbers like `1.22`, `1.24`, or `1.25` and to return also a `Decimal` number with only two digits. Here how it looks like (simplified with no `if`-blocks and other logic):

```
import decimal
TAX_22 = decimal.Decimal('1.22')

def wrap_on_tax(item):
  return item.money * TAX_22
```

But for this code I going to get a result `285.7362` for `money=234.21`. And I want to get `285.73`.

And I'm trying to find out most clear and pythonic way to do this.

Sure, I can just do a thing like this:

```
import decimal
TAX_22 = decimal.Decimal('1.22')

def wrap_on_tax(item):
  return decimal.Decimal('%.2f' % item.money * TAX_22)
```

And this approach will give me what I want. But typecasting a number to a string to get a number again doesn't look perfectly clear. I've tried to find any argument for `Decimal` constructor to tell it how many digits after comma I want, but I can't find anything.

Is there any more elegant way to get what I'm trying to get?

Comment: The correct result is `285.7362` and you want to get `285.73`. Does that mean you always want to round down after the second decimal? Like `math.floor(100 * 234.21 * 1.22) / 100`?

Comment: @Matthias yes, that's looks like what I want.

Comment: Making `TAX_22` a `Decimal` instance doesn't help with accuracy if `item.money` is already a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of data to processing and limited by decimal 2.

For Convenience, I suggest you use a new-type float as following.
You can do general calculation, like +, -, * and /, also calculate with general int or float number, almost same as float.

How to use it ? for example:

```py
TAX_22 = Digit2(1.22)
money = 234.21

def wrap_on_tax(money):
  return money * TAX_22

print(wrap_on_tax(money))    # 285.73
```

```
class Digit2(float):

    def __new__(cls, number):
        """
        if you need rounding, you can use this for next statement
        num = int(number*100 + 0.5)/100
        """
        num = int(number*100)/100
        return float.__new__(cls, num)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Digit2(float(self) + float(other))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Digit2(float(self) - float(other))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Digit2(float(self) * float(other))

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return Digit2(float(self) / float(other))

    def __neg__(self):
        return Digit2(-float(self))

    def __pos__(self):
        return self

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return -self.__sub__(other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return Digit2(float(other) / float(self))
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try split like this

```
def limitcomma(value, limit=2):
  v = str(value).split(".")
  return float(v[0]+"."+v[1][:limit])

print(limitcomma(0.1229384703))
```

the result will

```
0.12
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
     number = "285.7362"
     for i, s in enumerate(number):
         if "." in s:
         number_result = number[0:i+3]


     print(number_result)    # 285.73
```

Comment: As OP already suggested, type casting number to string to get number again, doesn't look perfectly clear, he's looking for different approach to this question, please read question fully before attempting to answer..